# jQuery Lightbox onComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using jQuery light box plugin (found here: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

I am wondering if there is a way to detect when the image is loaded so i can reinstate my selectors?

The problem is my stript:

```
$('#download').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

Does not work on the link that is loaded into the 'title' area of the lightbox.

Please Help

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using jQuery 1.3 or later, you can use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('#download').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

It will attach a click handler to the #download link, even if the link created in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for

```
$('#download').live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
//do other stuff when a click happens

});
```

`#download` will not be loaded into the DOM if you are creating it after the page has been loaded